# Coverage of ACTV Venezia Daily Pass

Tags: public-transport, europe, italy, italian-residents, venice

According to this website: https://www.veneziaunica.it/en/e-commerce/services?macrofamily=2&family=2

this is the coverage of the daily pass:

> ACTV 1 day Transport VENEZIA DAILY PASSACTV Public Transport Services (vaporetto and buses in the City of Venice, Tram/ People Mover) + Trenitalia urban network€ 25,00
> Validity: 1 day (24 hours)

> It includes ACTV Public Transport Services: vaporetto, buses in the City of Venice, Tram, People Mover service (Piazzale Roma - Maritime Station - Tronchetto) and the Trenitalia train service on Regional (R) and Fast Regional (RV) trains within the territory of the municipality of Venice (Venezia S. Lucia, Venezia P.to Marghera, Venezia Mestre, Venezia Carpenedo, Venezia Mestre Ospedale).

Does this mean this pass can also be used to go to Burano, Murano, and Tracello from Venice?

Can we also use this pass to use local **trams** or **busses** from Mestre center to Venice center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been to Burano and Murano using the pass (this year). They're on the vaporetto network.

Comment: were you also able to travel to and from Mestre (mainland?) using this pass?